# How to set AWS ALB instead of ELB in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, istio, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to setup ALB load balancer instead of default ELB loadbalancer in Kubernetes AWS.The loadbalancer has to be connected to the istio ingressgateway.I looked for solutions and only found [one](https://medium.com/@cy.chiang/how-to-integrate-aws-alb-with-istio-v1-0-b17e07cae156).
But the istio version mentioned is V1 and there has been so many changes in istio now.I tried to change service type to nodeport in the chart (according to the blog)but still the service comes as a Loadbalancer.

Can someone mention steps how to configure ALB for istio ingressgateway?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Step 1 : Change istioingresssgateway service type as nodeport
>
> Step 2 : Install ALB ingress controller
>
> Step 3 : Write ingress.yaml for istioingressgateway as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: ingress
  labels:
    app: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: <subnet1>,<subnet2>
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
              servicePort: 80
```

> alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets annotation can be avoided if you labelled subnet of vpc with :
>
> kubernetes.io/cluster/: owned
>
> kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb: 1 (for internal ELB)
>
> kubernetes.io/role/elb: 1 (for external ELB)

or else you can provide two subnet values and each subnet should be in different availability zone in the above yaml

> It worked in Istio 1.6

Comment: Does this still work for 1.8.0?  I keep getting failed health checks in the target group.

Comment: @MichaelMartin, and those looking to resolve the same problem. You need to alter ALB target group healtch check configuration to use Istio status port to be the health check port. Use the nodePort that maps Istio 15021 targetPort and /healthz/ready URL

Comment: I have followed the steps, in Istio 1.14.5 but the ALB does not get created. How would it get created though? In the same ingress-gateways service that already has a NodePort? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 4):

Current accepted answer is correct. However I would like to give a slight update to it.
Once AWS alb controller is installed and configured there are several steps one should take to make it work and be usable:

1. Use `istioctl manifest generate` command to generate a list of manifests
2. Find `istio-ingressgateway` service configuration
3. Update it to be of a NodePort type
4. Update ports configuration to have a pre-defined mapping of Node and Target ports. Note the `status-port` NodePort
5. Apply these manifests instead of installing/updating istio using `istioctl install` command. In some cases it might be better to rely on istio helm installation though
6. Update ingress configuration to have the following annotations

````
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: 'PORT'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz/ready
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP```
where PORT equals to the istio status-port NodePort value 

This way, you update ALB default configuration for the healthcheck to check Istio healthcheck
````

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm solution by tibin_tomy worked for me on Istio 1.7.4. Additionally I used ClusterIP under step 1 instead of NodePort.

Step1 - Change istioingresssgateway service type to ClusterIP (Installing Istio using IstioOperator):

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator

metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name:      istio
spec:
  profile: default
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        k8s:
          service:
            type: ClusterIP # Disable classic load balancer creation (default), routing to here will be done via Kubernetes Ingress resource
```

NOTE: Deploy "Ingress" in the same namespace as istio-ingressgateway (istio-system by default).
For example if istio-ingressgateway is in namespace istio-system and Ingress is in namespace system, then aws-alb-ingress-controller errors with:

> "kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to
> reconcile targetGroups due to failed to load serviceAnnotation due to
> no object matching key "system/istio-ingressgateway" in local store"
> "controller"="alb-ingress-controller"
> "request"={"Namespace":"system","Name":"sonata-ingress"}"