# Knative/Istio with AWS Application Load Balancers

Tags: kubernetes, istio, aws-application-load-balancer, knative, knative-serving

I have a question regarding the interaction between Knative serving, Istio, and AWS Application Load Balancers (ALB from now on).

I'm deploying Knative Serving v0.20 using the YAML manifests (not the `kn` console) and Istio using the Helm charts. Also, I've been following some online guides ([here](https://medium.com/@cy.chiang/how-to-integrate-aws-alb-with-istio-v1-0-b17e07cae156) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407364/how-to-set-aws-alb-instead-of-elb-in-istio)) to have Istio use an ALB instead of creating an ELB. According to them, the major configuration change needed to have Istio use the ALB is `gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type=NodePort`. That change makes Istio not create its load balancer.

However, I noticed that, when Istio does not create the load balancer, Kubernetes won't let me delete the following Knative ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1
metadata:
  annotations:
    networking.knative.dev/ingress.class: istio.ingress.networking.knative.dev
  creationTimestamp: '2021-03-09T12:52:30Z'
  deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  deletionTimestamp: '2021-03-09T13:13:30Z'
  finalizers:
    - ingresses.networking.internal.knative.dev
  generateName: default-domain-
  generation: 2
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:networking.knative.dev/ingress.class': {}
          'f:generateName': {}
        'f:spec':
          .: {}
          'f:rules': {}
      manager: default-domain
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-03-09T12:52:30Z'
    - apiVersion: networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:finalizers':
            .: {}
            'v:"ingresses.networking.internal.knative.dev"': {}
        'f:status':
          .: {}
          'f:conditions': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:privateLoadBalancer':
            .: {}
            'f:ingress': {}
          'f:publicLoadBalancer':
            .: {}
            'f:ingress': {}
      manager: controller
      operation: Update
      time: '2021-03-09T12:52:43Z'
  name: default-domain-fq97m
  namespace: knative-serving
  resourceVersion: '48071'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1/namespaces/knative-serving/ingresses/default-domain-fq97m
  uid: 84323bd8-018d-4d30-b933-91ebba604811
spec:
  rules:
    - hosts:
        - default-domain-tn6xq.default-domain.invalid
      http:
        paths:
          - splits:
              - percent: 100
                serviceName: default-domain-service
                serviceNamespace: knative-serving
                servicePort: 80
      visibility: ExternalIP
status:
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-03-09T12:52:43Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: LoadBalancerReady
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-03-09T12:52:30Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: NetworkConfigured
    - lastTransitionTime: '2021-03-09T12:52:43Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: Ready
  observedGeneration: 1
  privateLoadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - domainInternal: knative-local-gateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  publicLoadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - domainInternal: istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
```

I believe the main reason to be the `finalizers` section. As a matter of fact, if I modify the resource in the cluster, replacing

```
finalizers:
  - ingresses.networking.internal.knative.dev
```

with `finalizers: []` then Kubernetes lets me destroy it.

I searched for an explanation in the documentation and online, but haven't found any. At first, I thought I was messing up with the AWS ALB controller, so I tried to change Istio's configuration without creating any ALBs but the issue wouldn't disappear.

Do you know what that Ingress is used for and how can I solve (or, at least, work around) this issue? Pointers to relevant discussions/examples/docs are welcome as well!

Thank you so much!